# Does there exist an infinite sequence $p_0,p_1,p_2...$ of prime numbers such that $p_k=4 p_{k-1}\pm 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

$k \in Z^+$

firstly we know that there exists infinetly many primes of the form $4n+1$ by FTA
also we see that if we consider finite primes say to $n$ then the recursive formular can be expressed as:

$p_k=4p_{k-1}+1=4^kp_0+4^{k-1}+4^{k-2}...+4^2+4+1=4^kp_0+\frac{4^{k}-1}{3}$

since $4\equiv 1 \mod 3$ we know there exists such an integral number $p_k$

Comment: Your last comment makes no sense; $4^k$ is *always* congruent to $1 \bmod 3$ (as $4\equiv 1\bmod 3$).  And since $p_k$ is _also_ defined as $4p_{k-1}+1$, it should be obvious from the definition that $p_i$ _must_ be integral for all $i$.

Comment: noted thanks,but i was using the notion of order of 4 mod 3:
$\phi(3)=2|k$ so k can only be even,but your argument above is true

Comment: It looks like in your displayed formula you assumed each $p_k$ is $4p_{k-1}+1$, yet in the question you allow $4p_{k-1}\pm 1$.

Comment: yes i am assuming the difference will just be analogous, $p_k=4^kp_0\pm \frac{4^k-1}{3}$

Comment: @Jonas12 Only if you choose the same sign each step of the way - but as noted in both answers, you can't get more than two 'steps' that way before hitting a number divisible by $3$.  The question is actually (slightly) more interesting if you allow either choice at every step, in which case the explicit formulae don't apply.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such sequence. For if there is, there is a sequence that starts at a number greater than $5$. We assume there is such a sequence, and derive a contradiction.

If $p$ is a term of the sequence, and is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, then we must take $4p+1$ as the next term to avoid divisibility by $3$. We then get a number congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. Similarly, if we are at a number $q$ congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, we must go to $4q-1$, and we get a number congruent to $1$ modulo $3$.

So $\pm 1$ must alternate if we are to keep getting primes.

Now it is straightforward to verify that if we start with a number not divisible by $5$, then one of the next $4$ terms is divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Your instinct of looking at divisibility by $3$ is a good one; you just need to look at it a from a slightly different angle.  Firstly, note that since $4\equiv 1\bmod 3$, $p_k\equiv p_{k-1}\pm1\bmod 3$; this means that two consecutive $+1$ steps are impossible, since if $p\equiv 2\bmod 3$ then $4p+1\equiv 0\bmod 3$ so it can't possibly be prime, and likewise if $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$ then $4(4p+1)+1\equiv 0\bmod 3$.  Similarly, there can't be two consecutive $-1$ steps for exactly the same reason.  So assuming $p_0\equiv 1\bmod 3$ (if it's not, we can just 'start' on $p_1$ instead), we know that we must have $p_1=4p_0+1$, $p_2=4p_1-1$, $p_3=4p_2+1$, etc; the $\pm$ must alternate signs to avoid divisibility by 3.  But this implies that $p_{2n+2}$ $= 4p_{2n+1}-1$ $= 4(4p_{2n}+1)-1$ $=16p_{2n}-3$.  Now, consider $p_i \bmod 5$ and show that at least one of $p_{2n}, p_{2n+2}, p_{2n+4}, p_{2n+6}, p_{2n+8}$ must be divisible by $5$.